# Proving upper bound for the number of solutions of Diophantine equation

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

> Let $p$ be a sufficiently large prime number. Show that the number of ordered pairs of positive integers $(a,b,c,d)$ satisfying
> \[ab+cd=p\]does not exceed $\frac{3p^2}8$.

I did not see how $p$ being prime helps, and simply did
\[T_p:=\#\{(a,b,c,d)\in\Bbb N_+^4\mid ab+cd=p\}=\sum_{i=1}^{p-1}\tau(i)\cdot\tau(p-i),\]
where $\tau(\cdot)$ counts the number of positive factors.

By using the estimation $\tau(n)\le16\sqrt[3]n$, it suffices to prove
\[T_p\le256\sum_{i=1}^{p-1}\sqrt[3]{pi-i^2}\le\frac{3p^2}8.\]

I'm not sure if it is strong enough.

---

Edit: I've solved it with an easy method.

By Hölder inequality,
\begin{align*}\small
256\sum_{i=1}^{p-1}\sqrt[3]i\cdot\sqrt[3]{p-i}\cdot\sqrt[3]1&\small\le256\sqrt[3]{\textstyle\left(\sum\limits_{i=1}^{p-1}i\right)\left(\sum\limits_{i=1}^{p-1}(p-i)\right)\sum\limits_{i=1}^{p-1}1}\\
&\small=256\sqrt[3]{\frac{p^2(p-1)^3}4},
\end{align*}
which is less than $\frac{3p^2}8$ for sufficiently large $p$.

Comment: The number of solutions of $ab+cd=n$ is tabulated at https://oeis.org/A055507 – no estimates are given, but several links to the literature are given, and maybe somewhere there there's an estimate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yoichi Motohashi, The binary additive divisor problem, Annales scientifiques de l’É.N.S. 4e série, tome 27, no 5 (1994), p. 529-572, attributes to Ingham the result,
$$
D(N)=\sum_{n=1}^{n-1}d(n)d(N-n)=(1+o(1)){6\over\pi^2}\sigma(N)(\log N)^2
$$
The Ingham citation is A.E. INGHAM, Some Asymptotic Formulae in the Theory of Numbers (J . London Math. Soc., Vol. 2, 1927, pp. 202-208). Motohashi may go on to improve on this, but I didn't look any further. The Motohashi paper is available at http://www.numdam.org/item/10.24033/asens.1700.pdf

Of course, in the case where $N$ is prime, we have $\sigma(N)=N+1$.

Comment: Thanks. I'll take a look. For now could you tell me whether the order of magnitude of\\[\frac{1}{4} (-3) \sqrt[3]{p} \left(\, _2F_1\left(-\frac{1}{3},\frac{4}{3};\frac{7}{3};\frac{1}{p}\right)-(p-1)^{4/3} \, _2F_1\left(-\frac{1}{3},\frac{4}{3};\frac{7}{3};\frac{p-1}{p}\right)\right)\\]is less than that of $p^2$? (because I don't know what this means and if it works, I'll also keep trying my method)

Comment: Sorry, I don't know anything about growth rates of hypergeometric functions.

Comment: It's okay. Mathematica computed\\[\lim_{p\to+\infty}\frac{\rm that~long~expression}{p^2}=0,\\]which I think is enough.

Comment: When you wrote, "I don't know what this means", were you referring to your formula with the hypergeometric functions in it? or were you referring to the equation in my answer? Does your hypergeometric formula have anything to do with your question about solutions to $ab+cd=n$? The equation in my answer shows that the number of solutions, if $n$ is prime, is bounded by a constant times $n$ times the square of $\log n$, which is a lot stronger than saying it goes to zero when you divide by $n^2$ and let $n$ go to infinity.

Comment: I'm referring to the function $_2F_1(~)$ functions. By the way, I've got an easy method to solve it.

Comment: Where do you get the estimation, $\tau(n)\le16\root3\of n$?

Comment: I'll post a proof, probably later.

Comment: I think you may be misquoting Holder. $\sum a_i^{1/3}b_i^{1/3}\le(\sum a_i\sum b_i)^{1/3}$ doesn't work. E.g., take $a_1=b_1=27$, $a_2=b_2=64$, then left side is $9+16=25$, right side is $91^{2/3}=20.23$. But there is a pretty simple proof of $\tau(n)\le4\root3\of n$ on pages 56-58 of Stopple, A Primer of Analytic Number Theory.

Comment: I corrected it.